# It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container

Tags: docker, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I m trying to run my vuejs app using vs-code remote-containers. Its deployed and I can access it via the url: localhost:8080/ but If I update some js file, its not re-compiling and even not hot-reloading.

devcontainer.json

```
{
    "name": "Aquawebvue",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "appPort": [3000],
    "runArgs": ["-u", "node"],
    "settings": {
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Cobalt2",
        "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "postCreateCommand": "yarn",
    "extensions": [
        "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "wesbos.theme-cobalt2",
    ]
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.13.0
RUN npm install -g prettier
```

After opening container and running cmd 'yarn serve' in terminal it builds and deploy successfully but I got this warning:

```
  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.

  Since you are using a non-root publicPath, the hot-reload socket
  will not be able to infer the correct URL to connect. You should
  explicitly specify the URL via devServer.public.
```

Comment: Why are you introducing Docker into this workflow?  What benefits are you hoping to get over just using Node on your host system?

Comment: I want to tryout different versions of vue-cli, webpack and some other global modules

Answer (score 3):

VSCode has a pre-defined `.devcontainer` directory for Vue projects. It can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/master/containers/vue). You can install it automatically by running the command **Add Development Container Configuration Files... > Show All Definitions > Vue**.

[image: VSCode / Add Development Container Configuration Files command]

### Dockerfile

```
# [Choice] Node.js version: 14, 12, 10
ARG VARIANT=14
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-${VARIANT}

RUN su node -c "umask 0002 && npm install -g http-server @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global"
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
# RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
#     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends <your-package-list-here>
```

### devcontainer.json

```json
{
    "name": "Vue (Community)",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": "..",
        // Update 'VARIANT' to pick a Node version: 10, 12, 14
        "args": { "VARIANT": "14" }
    },

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/zsh"
    },
    
    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "octref.vetur"
    ],
    
    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    "forwardPorts": [
        8080
    ],
    
    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "uname -a",
    
    // Comment out connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "node"
}
```